# How to display UIView over keyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikeyboard

I want to create a simple view over keyboard, when users tap "Attach" button in inputAccessoryView. 
Something like this:

[image]

Is there an easy way to do it? Or i should create my custom keyboard?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can add that new subview to your application window.

```
func attach(sender : UIButton)
{
    // Calculate and replace the frame according to your keyboard frame
    var customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height-300, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 300))
    customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    customView.layer.zPosition = CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)
    var windowCount = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.count
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows[windowCount-1].addSubview(customView);
}
```

Comment: You could use `sender.window` instead of `UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows[...]`?

Comment: @rintaro: That won't work, that will add the view below the keyboard

Comment: This is a hacky solution and should be avoided. The window hierarchy can change on any newly introduced iOS version.

Comment: this one not support for ios 16 , cannot add view over keybbaord, anything to fixedthis ?

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 4 version:**

```
let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height - 300, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 300))
customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
customView.layer.zPosition = CGFloat(Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.addSubview(customView)
```

The trick is to add the `customView` as a top subview to the `UIWindow` that holds the keyboard - and it happens to be the last window in `UIApplication.shared.windows`.

Comment: Getting last of  `windows` rather than `keyWindow` from UIApplication works!

Comment: Hey, this code doesn't work with Xcode 14.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4.0**

```
let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height-300, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 300))
customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
customView.layer.zPosition = CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)
let windowCount = UIApplication.shared.windows.count
UIApplication.shared.windows[windowCount-1].addSubview(customView)
```

Answer (score 4):

As Tamás Sengel said, Apple's guidelines does not support adding a view over the keyboard. The recommended way to add a view over keyboard in Swift 4 & 5 is:

1) Add view with your "Next" button in your storyboard as external view and connect in your class (see Explain Image), in my case:

```
IBOutlet private weak var toolBar: UIView!
```

2) For the textfield you want to add your custom view over keyboard, add it as accessory view in viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    phoneNumberTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
}
```

3) Add action for "Next" button:

```
@IBAction func nextButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    descriptionTextView.becomeFirstResponder()

    // or -> phoneNumberTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

**Explain Image**:
[image]

**Method 2: Result with image**

[image]

**In TableView Controller - add stricked view at bottom**

Please follow this great link to handle safe area for screens like iPhone X if you want to use this method(2). Article: [InputAccessoryView and iPhone X](https://medium.com/code-with-rohit/inputaccessoryview-and-iphonex-7b5547fe98da)

```
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    return toolBar
}

override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: This  should be the correct answer. Thanks user doca. You are the man.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have find some effective method to solve this problem? In iOS9,you put your customView on the top of the windows:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows[windowCount-1].addSubview(customView);
```

But if the keyboard dismisses, the top Windows will be removed, so your `customView` will be removed. 
Looking forward for your help! 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please see my answer, i solve this problem like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32598490/show-uiview-with-buttons-over-keyboard-like-in-skype-viber-messengers-swift-i

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely add the view to your application’s window, and you can also add another window entirely. You can set its frame and level. The level could be `UIWindowLevelAlert`.

Answer (score 0):

While this can be possible with accessing the topmost window, I would **avoid** doing this, as it clearly interferes with Apple's guidelines.

What I would do is dismissing the keyboard and replacing its frame with a view with same dimensions.

The keyboard's frame can be accessed from keyboard notifications listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html), their `userInfo` contain a key that can be accessed with `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`.