# Autolayout : How to create a simple UIView over keyboard using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, toolbar

I want to create a simple UIView over keyboard works in AutoLayout.

Here is an example of Yik Yak UIView.

[image]

I checked [Show UIView with buttons over keyboard, like in Skype,Viber messengers (Swift, iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32598490/show-uiview-with-buttons-over-keyboard-like-in-skype-viber-messengers-swift-i) but didn't works well.

Comment: The link you found is not your problem. You just need get the keyboard height from keyboard notifications, and set the buttons at the right 'height'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using notifications, calculating sizes etc., why not use the `inputAccessoryView`? here is an example from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/KeyboardAccessory/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I tried to add a button to upload image but it didn't works will it seems only for clear or done  https://github.com/SabatinoMasala/accessoryview-demo

Comment: Your example you gave is using calculating sizes based on notifications :)

Comment: @sunshine, it does :-) but it's not explicitly needed for an accessory view, it's needed for what they're trying to do in their sample code.

Answer (score 3):

So, because of the availability of custom keyboards in iOS 8, you need to do few things in order to achieve view above the keyboard.

1. First, add observers for `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and
   `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`, this will make sure you got the
   newest frame of the keyboard.
2. Second, add your constraint to bottom of the view. Also connect this
   constraint with your ViewController, to have it as a property.
3. Third, in the methods when `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and
   `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`fire up, you can get the frame of
   the keyboard like:
   `notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]`, then change
   the bottom constraint you have in your ViewController accordingly (+ when showing, - when hiding).

Comment: Thank you sunshine do you have a link to an example that I can Follow , am New to swift

Comment: See the link @iMoses provided, its actually using the method I described, look in ViewController and registering notifications, plus keyboardWillShow and WillHide methods. Just do it with swift syntax.